# Dependency clash between Apache CXF and Kie Remote Client

Tags: maven, apache-camel, cxf, kie

I'm currently writing an Apache Camel project that's using CXF to expose some REST endpoints and Kie Remote Client to interface with BPMS. However, I'm getting a dependency clash (not sure how to describe it) when I try to include the Kie Remote Client dependency into my pom file.

Here's my pom file currently:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Camel Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-parent-with-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-remote-client </artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
```

When I try to deploy my project I'm getting some property exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested     PropertyAccessExceptions (2) are:
PropertyAccessException 1:  org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'serviceBeans'  threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.addToBeans(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

PropertyAccessException 2:  org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'providers' threw  exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.addToBeans(Ljava/util/Collection;Lj ava/lang/Object;)V
at  org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractProp ertyAccessor.java:121) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at  org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.appl yPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510) [spring-beans- 4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6
```

Anyone know what's the root cause of this error? Thanks!

EDIT: I did find a temporary workaround to this problem. If I downgrade my camel versions to 2.13.2 and my spring versions to 3.2.8-RELEASE then the apache-cxf versions seem to aligh. However there are many new features that I need in 2.15.2 camel that I would like to keep. Anyone know of any good alternatives to kie.remote.client?

Answer (score 0):

Kie remote client add the jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar dependency, in collition with jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar and jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar from cxf.

just remove the jaxb-impl from you deploy. (or use maven exclusion in dependency of kie-client) it's works for me.